# Symfony2 while adding on cascade forms update sub forms with reference fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using symfony2 forms, in which there are also sub forms

For eg

```
$builder->add('aaa')
        ->add('bbb')
        ->add('ccc',new ccc() //CCC entity has more than one fields
```

This is working fine on Add and edit, if we add new ccc along with form

```
$em->persist($build);
$em->flush();
```

the problem is now that i need reuse the `ccc` by clicking autocomplete which fills all n values in entity `ccc`.

```
$cc = $em->getRepository('Acme:cc')->findBy(array("externalId"=>$build->getCcc()->getExternalId()));

$build->getCcc()->setId($cc->getId); //It is not possible because there is no setId method available
(and)
$build->setCcc($cc); //If is set like this add page edit details not saved
//If i do nothing it will duplicate the ccc values
```

How i need to update the ccc if the id is present?

Is there anyway to merge the object or clone the object to get only value is available?

thanks

Comment: can you elaborate? i dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @shaheer on cascading form, i have entity form type which has multiple fields, on adding i need to check if it is already present then update or insert new! can it be possible

Comment: with doctrine you dont have to check that, it will happen automatically, anyway i guess the value is in the dropdown?

Comment: @shaheer yes if we give entity has select, what if we give entity as new form type? always it will add new - but i dont want to add always